# Android list views with groups

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, android-adapter

I'm a beginner on Android.
At this point I've implemented a couple of `ListView`s, and and also an `ExpandableListView`.

Now I'd like to get a `ListView` with groups / sections and I liked the implementation of `ExpandableListView` to get groups. However I do not want the expand / collapsed ability. 
I've searched a bit and it doesn't appear that it is possible, it looks like I need to use `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType(int)`.

Maybe I'm wrong but it feels that this kind of implementation is dirtier than a `BaseExpandableListAdapter`.

What can / should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `BaseExpandableAdapter` with an `ExpandableListView` to get those features.

Two of the methods you mentioned don't appear on that adapter: getViewType() and getViewTypeCount() only appear on the normal `BaseAdapter`.   They have analogs called getGroupType(), getChildType(), etc -- but you can ignore these for now.

What you need to implement to get the group/child features are getChildrenCount(), getChildView().  The "type" methods are only if you want to use different layout files for your items.  But to simply get groups with children the "type" methods don't need to be implemented.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to disable the expand / collapse feature I don't want?

Comment: Return zero for `getChildrenCount(int group)` for any group/parent you don't want to have children.